# What physical quantity is a black hole singularity refering to and why is it special?

Tags: black-holes, singularities

What mathematical term actually shows a "singularity" in a black hole and why is this so special compared to other singularities? It seems super hard to find any concrete formulas about the black hole theories.

I mean, Newtonian central forces have a mathematical singularity at $r=0$ as well (e.g. gravitation and electromagnetics, because $1/r²$).

Lets take a non-spinning electrical neutral object with mass just before collapsing to a black hole. All fine. Then one single tiny additional elctrical neutral non-spinning particle (like a neutron) gets fired into this object so that it just increases the mass over the critial mass and "generates" the Schwarzschild radius. This apperently causes a singularity out of nothing, without smooth transition. But a singularity *of what*? A force? A mass? A charge? A density? Isn't there a smooth transition of some kind?

What is the exact defintion of the term "singularity" here?

Comment: See Wikipedia’s articles on [gravitational singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_singularity) and [curvature invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_invariant).

Comment: An infinite curvature invariant indicates a singularity where spacetime fails to be a manifold. Since spacetime is the stage upon which all of physics happens, a singularity in spacetime *itself* is more “special” than a singularity in, say, an electric field *in* spacetime.

Comment: “*But a singularity of what? A force? A mass? A charge? A density?*” - The end of time. Gravity bends the direction of time. Things fall down to the Earth simply by moving forward in time, but their direction of time is bent down by the Earth. The extreme gravity of a black hole bends time to move toward the center. All timelines of everything reach there and have nowhere to go causing time to end. A Schwarzschild singularity is the end of time for everything that gets there. The “quantity” you are looking for is the abrupt end of all timelike and lightlike geodesics (timelines of all matter).

Comment: @Ghoster Let’s take for example a two-sphere. It is two-dimensional manifold with intrinsic curvature $K=1/r^2$ and surface area $A=4 \pi r^2$. Both quantities depend on the size of your meter stick. What is invariant is their product $A \cdot K = 4 \pi$. As a result in the limit of zero surface area ($ A \rightarrow 0 $) the curvature K diverges like $1/r^2$. However, because a two-sphere is not contractible to a point the infinite curvature manifold is still regular, even with the zero surface area (singularity). The infinity and zero are thought here as limits.